# How to extend HTMLButtonAttribute type in JSX

Tags: typescript, jsx, stenciljs

I'm creating a simple button component using StencilJS which uses JSX and TypeScript. The current stable version doesn't have a type for the attribute `part`. Basically I'm trying to do this:

```
render() {
   return <button part="live-chat-button">{this.getStartButtonText()} </button>;
}
```

But Typescript errors with:

```
Type '{ part: string; }' is not assignable to type 
'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'. Property
'part' does not exist on type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.
```

Apart from upgrading to the fixed [alpha version](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/commit/abc7f65595f27f7d0b2e437e4cafb6d0b341b0c8), how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add attributes to any jsx element using module augmentation:

```
declare module '@stencil/core' {
  namespace JSXElements {
    interface ButtonHTMLAttributes<T> {
      part?: string
    }
  }
}
```

This should work for button.

Comment: This seems to overwrite the entire namespace rather than adding to it.